# com usar D3.js offline

Tags: javascript, d3.js

tem como usar o D3.js offline?
Normalmente uso o script normal
 para usar online.

mas estou necessitando de uma forma de trabalhar com D3 offline

Comment: Bem-vindo, para obter respostas que solucionem sua dúvida / problema leia [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **O que você quer dizer com online?** Esta falando do caminho na tag script: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>` ? Você quer usar em um WEBAPP, MobileApp, webView local?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você deve fazer é baixar os arquivos, e extrair no diretório do seu projeto, exemplo:

```
Projeto
- js ( Diretório que contém seus arquivos Javascript )
-- d3 ( Diretório contendo os arquivos d3js )
```

Você deve chamar ele em seu código.

```
<script src="js/d3/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Boa resposta, espero que seja isso o que ele procura, mas recomendo mesmo que quando a pergunta não for tão clara, ou for muito ampla contenha-se um pouco e espere o autor editar a pergunta, também é interessante usar o link Sinalizar para dizer que tem algo errado na pergunta, no caso selecionar a opção: Não está clara. Leia mais em: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, verdade. O dedo fica coçando rsrs, mas peguei o conselho e estarei lendo.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode baixar a biblioteca e trabalhar com ela em offline: https://d3js.org/

@edit

Mas para isso você precisa compilar ela.
Após baixada e extraída em algum lugar, entre na pasta resultado da extração e de os seguintes comandos:
`npm i`
`npm prepublishOnly`

com isso será gerada uma pasta `build`.
Entre nessa e copie o arquivo d3.js ou d3.min.js.
Dai cole no seu projeto, onde você armazena os arquivos js, ou na pasta de sua escolha. Então no seu index.html referencie ele. ex:

```
    <body>
    <script src="d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    d3.select("body").append("h1").text("Hello, world!");
```

Comment: eu já baixei mas não consigo usar tenho que rodar um servidor local ou coisa parecida?

Comment: mas lembre-se de informar o caminho corretamente, e caso o use o d3.js, ponha src="d3.js", em vez de src="d3.mim.js"

Comment: você pode encontrar os passos por aqui https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/bb09af4c39c79cffcde4